# ruby on rails undefined method form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use PaperClip inside my application.

I have 3 models: menu, user and pub. I would like the user to be able to add a menu, which is a pdf file, for a pub. So when I upload the pdf file, I would like to have a column in the menu model with the pub id.

menu.rb

```
    has_attached_file :document
    validates_attachment :document, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(application/pdf)}
```

new.html.erb

```
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Upload Menu</h1></div>

    <%= form_for ([@pub, @menu]), html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
     <%= text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.label :document %>
    <%= f.file_field :document, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Upload Menu', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
     resources: pubs do
           resources :menus
     end
```

menus_controller.rb

```
     class MenusController < ApplicationController

     def index
        @menus = Menu.order('created_at')
     end
     def new
         @menu = Menu.new
     end
     def create
        @pub = Pub.find(params[:pub_id])
        input = menu_params.merge(pub: @pub)
        @menu = current_user.menus.build(input)
      if @menu.save
         flash[:success] = "Successfully added new menu!"
         redirect_to root_path
      else
         flash[:alert] = "Error adding new menu!"
         render :new
      end
      end


    private

   def menu_params
       params.require(:menu).permit(:title, :document)
   end

   end
```

Button for the new page to upload a file

```
        <%= link_to "Upload menu", new_pub_menu_path(@pub), class: 'btn btn-primary'  %>
```

So when I click the button, I get to the new_pub_menu_path(@pub) generated link, but I have an error ..

error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `menus_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f652ce54550>:0x007f652c90c9a8>
Did you mean?  user_path):
1: 
2: <%= form_for ([@pub, @menu]), html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
3:   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
4: 
5:   <div class="form-group">
```

What should I do? I tried to use the nested routes so to have in the url the id pub, but when the new.html.file is rendered it gives me that error. I don't know what method menus_path is. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `menus_path' for

You didn't defined `@pub` in `new` method of `menus_controller`, so `@pub` is `nil` in `new.html.erb`, so is the error. Define it to resolve the issue.

```
def new
  @menu = Menu.new
  @pub = Pub.find(params[:pub_id])
end
```